# Why does getContainer()->get('mailer') mean to create an instance of the Swift_Mailer?

Tags: symfony

I don't understand, how are class aliases defined.

Where does Symfony know from, that getContainer()->get('mailer') means to create an instance of the Swift_Mailer?

Comment: What version of Symfony do you use? Have you looked for "mailer" in yaml/xml files of your project? I bet you'll find it there

Comment: I use the version 4.1
And I haven't  found it in the config files

Comment: I see. Have looked in /vendor directory? By default PHPStorm looks into project files only.

Comment: Where in /vendor? There are a lot of files, that contain "mailer".

Comment: The SwiftMailerBundle is used to configure the mailer service.  vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Resources/config/swiftmailer.xml

Comment: yes, but wich option in this file is responsible for 'mailer'? And there is no 'mailer' in the file

Comment: swiftmailer-bundle/DependencyInjection/SwiftmailerExtension.php.  Config files are only the first step.  In many cases, an extension is used to dynamically create and modify services.

Answer (score 1):

In `/vendor/symfony/-bundle/DependencyInjection/SwiftmailerExtension.php` at line 71 (Symfony 4.1) `mailer` is defined as alias for service `swiftmailer.mailer`:

```
$container->setAlias('mailer', 'swiftmailer.mailer');
$container->getAlias('mailer')->setPublic(true);
```